# Running total on acumatica's customer details page (AR402000)

Tags: c#, acumatica

am trying to add 2 fields to the customer details page one for the document amount running total in original currency and one for document amount running total for each currency, I created a variable in the graph extension for assigning the total for the original currency and a dictionary for holding the running total for the currency and its respective total, The running totals for both fields are working properly in the first page/record list but when i click next the first value on the next page starts the counting process again from zero and also duplicates. Is there a way I can forward the running total to the next list of records and also avoid the duplicating of the first value on each page of records after the first one? here is code am using for the calculations

```
public decimal AllCurTotals = 0; //summation of doc amt in original currency 
Dictionary<string, decimal> curydict =  new Dictionary<string, decimal>(); //summation of doc amt in seprate currencies
protected void ARDocumentResult_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{         
           ARDocumentEnq.ARDocumentResult row = (ARDocumentEnq.ARDocumentResult)e.Row;
          if (row == null) return;
          ARRegisterExt extobj = cache.GetExtension<ARRegisterExt>(row);
          AllCurTotals += row.OrigDocAmt ?? 0;
          cache.SetValue<ARRegisterExt.usrrunningtot>(row, AllCurTotals);   
          if (curydict.ContainsKey(row.CuryID))
            {
              curydict[row.CuryID] += row.CuryOrigDocAmt ?? 0;
              extobj.Usrrunningtotpercur = curydict[row.CuryID];
            }
           else
            {
              curydict[row.CuryID] = row.CuryOrigDocAmt ?? 0;
              extobj.Usrrunningtotpercur = curydict[row.CuryID];

            }        
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RowSelected is not called once per record so this approach won't work for calculating the total of the visible rows in the grid.

I recommend you use the data view delegate to calculate sums based on visible records on screen.

```
public IEnumerable dataView()
{
       PXView select = new PXView(this, true, DataView.View.BqlSelect);
       Int32 totalrow = 0;
       Int32 startrow = PXView.StartRow;
       List<object> result = select.Select(PXView.Currents, PXView.Parameters,        
       PXView.Searches, PXView.SortColumns, PXView.Descendings, 
       PXView.Filters, ref startrow, PXView.MaximumRows, ref totalrow);
       PXView.StartRow = 0;
       foreach (PXResult<Contract, ContractBillingSchedule, CSAnswers> row in result)
       {
              //Do any dynamic calculations
       }

       return result;
}
```

source: http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/06/using-pxview-in-dataview-delegate.html

Comment: the data view the grid is using is already implemented as a method returning an IEnumerable type

Comment: Does that method has the same name as the data view and begins with a lower-case letter? If that's the case then this is the data view delegate because that is the convention for naming them. You should be able to iterate the IEnumerable collection in that method like in the example I posted. This would contain only visible records on screen. You could also modify the select if you need to calculate from record 0 up to last record visible in the grid, just be sure to return only the records that should be visible on screen according to PXView.StartRow and PXView.MaximumRows.